# Deploying Codeigniter4 application on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, digital-ocean-apps

I'm trying to deploy a CodeIgniter4 app on digital ocean app platform.

I'm using environment variables in my app. Problem is, I need to declare the base url as an environment variable. According to CodeIgniter's docs this can be done by declaring app.baseURL as a variable. But digital oceans platform only allows alphanumeric characters and underscores for a environment variable name, so I cant declare app.baseURL because of the dot.

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeIgniter docs:

**"Some environments do not permit variable name with dots. In such case, you could also use _ as a seperator."**